# After using EntityManager::create on existing entity i receive wrong data

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

i´m trying change entity manager data dinamicaly and use `EntityManager::create` and after that new entinty is conected to old entity. Symfony 4.3

db_user_0.room: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, db_user_1.room: `[1,2,3,4]`

```
$pem = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('db_private');

$params = $pem->getConnection()->getParams();
$params['dbname'] = 'db_user_1';

$configuration = $pem->getConfiguration();
$event_manager = $pem->getEventManager();

$cem = EntityManager::create($params, $configuration, $event_manager);


dd($cem->getRepository(room::class)->findAll()); // return [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

```
$pem->getConnection()->getParams() => array:9 [
    "driver" => "pdo_mysql"
    "host" => "127.0.0.1"
    "port" => null
    "user" => "root"
    "password" => ""
    "dbname" => "db_user_0"
    "charset" => "UTF8"
    "driverOptions" => []
    "defaultTableOptions" => []
]
```

I expected `[1,2,3,4]` but received `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: See if $params['url'] exists.  If it does then dbname will get overwritten from it when the connection is opened.

Comment: `
$params => array:9 [
  "driver" => "pdo_mysql"
  "host" => "127.0.0.1"
  "port" => null
  "user" => "root"
  "password" => ""
  "dbname" => "db_user_0"
  "charset" => "UTF8"
  "driverOptions" => []
  "defaultTableOptions" => []
]
`

Comment: Best to update your question with the $params values.  Comments don't format well.  Use the edit link in the lower left corner.

Comment: Use $cem->getConnection()->getDatabase() to confirm that your new entity manager is connecting to the original database.  I would have expected that $pem->getConnection()->getParams(); to have returned more information.  All I can really suggest is tracing through EntityManager::create to see what is happening.  The code does get a bit messy.

Comment: `$cem->getConnection()->getDatabase()` return `db_user_1`

Comment: seting default to `db_user_1` and new to `db_user_0` return values of `db_user_1` and its is `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Seems like the unit of work is being shared.  You might try $cem->reset();  though I suspect that that will end up resetting $pem as well.  This [article](https://medium.com/@raito.akehanareru/two-databases-with-symfony-4-doctrine-2-not-as-straightforward-as-it-might-look-906e57cee710) might help.

Comment: `$cem->reset()` -> `Attempted to call an undefined method named "reset" of class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".`

Comment: i tested `$pem->refresh($cem);` -> The class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

Comment: Sorry.  I meant $cem->clear();

Comment: `$cem->clear()` not resolved

Comment: when i try to put wrong credentials i receive `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_user_1'`